# How can I write my JSON data to external Storage

Tags: java, android

I want to write my Arraylist to external Storage. The File should be in Json format.

FILE_NAME = notes.json

```
private boolean isExternalStorageWritable(){
    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
        System.out.println("Storage is writeable");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
 private void wirteFile(){
    if(isExternalStorageWritable()){
        File textFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FILE_NAME);
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(textFile);
            fos.write(arrlist.toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first transform your ArrayList into a JSONObject. Then, just call `toString()`method on the created object.

```
if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FILE_NAME);
  JSONObject jsonObject = fromArrayList(arrayList); // you have to develop it

  try {
    Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    output.write(jsonObject.toString());
    output.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

With FileOutputStream

```
  try {
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    output.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
    output.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I give you an example to convert your data into JSONObject

```
public class ListItem {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public ListItem(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public JSONObject toJSONObject() {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("Id", id);
            object.put("Name", name);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            trace("JSONException: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

And then,

```
public JSONObject fromArrayList(ArrayList<ListItem> arrayList) {
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
  for (int i=0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    jsonArray.put(arrayList.get(i).toJSONObject());
  }
  object.put("result", jsonArray);
  return object;
}
```

Comment: how can i develop fromArrayList

Comment: It depends on your model...I advice you to create a method inside your model, called `toJSON()` to convert your data in a JSON object. Then, to convert your ArrayList, just have to iterate on all items

Comment: Is it possible to write to ExternalStorage with FileOutputStream and how would it look like

Comment: see my edited answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I can't do JSONObject put = object.put(arraylist);

Comment: fixed. Note that you can use any string you want instead of `result`

Comment: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/notes.json: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) got this error now

Comment: You have to manage the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: I gave that permission

Comment: Got it! You have to add in the application Tag of the AndroidManifest.xml    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". Thanks mate you helped me a lot